# Can I automate a process of checking SharePoint list column's property changes?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, task-list

I have 300 SharePoint 2010 lists. Occasionally users change Groups in the column "Assigned To". I have to check if those groups were changed and choose original group back. Is there any way (code free) to know if someone changed SharePoint Group in column "Assigned To"? (can use SP Designer)

Answer (score 0):

If you using content types on library or list, put there column with back up info like *Assigned TO backup* and make it hidden.

Prepare workflow on item change.

In workflow compare column *Assigned To* with *Assigned To backup*.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column called "Originally Assigned To" for each list and hide this from forms and views.

Create two workflows the first will be triggered when item is created and the second when modified.

workflow 1:
Update currentitem:Originally Assigned To **(value of current item Assigned To)**

workflow 2:
If currentitem:Originally Assigned To does not equal currentitem:Assigned To
Email **(Who ever needs to pick these up)**

Doing this as two separate workflows prevents the originally assigned to column being updated to the new value when the item is modified.